# Function which Takes a binary tree and prints out its values in order

Tags: haskell

I am currently writing a a function to take a binary tree and print out its values in the right order(in order transversal).The problem i have is i keep getting a non exhaustive pattern error when ever i call the function

```
 --k is the key and d is the value
 -- l is left tree and r is right tree
treeprint (Node l k d r)      =  treeprint l  ++ show k ++ show d ++ treeprint r 
treeprint Nil=""
```

Comment: That's because you haven't covered all the possible cases. How will you function treat `Node Nil k1 d1 (Node Nil k2 d2 Nil)`? I suggest rejigging things so that you have one case for `Nil` and one for `(Node l k d r)`, and that way you're sure to have everything covered.

Comment: I dont get what you mean by rejigging.Do you mean i should have guards in the second line to match different edge cases

Comment: I mean that you should not treat "different edge cases" at all: they're the source of your error. Treat general cases only! Write two lines, beginning `treeprint Nil = ???` and `treeprint (Node l k d r) = ???`. Then figure out what each `???` should be.

Comment: I have one case for nil and one case for  Node l k d r.Please Can you point me in the right direction

Comment: @Jackwelch Your code above has one case for `Node Nil _ _ Nil` and another for `Node _ _ _ _`. It does *not* have a case for `Nil`. If you have changed your code, please update the question.

Comment: @Jackwelch Can you give us please an example of a tree for which `treeprint` gives a non exhaustive pattern error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *seem* to have solved your problem, except you need some brackets and spaces.

### Your (current) version

I assume you're using

```
data Tree k d = Nil | Node (Tree k d) k d (Tree k d)
```

although you didn't say. I'll define an example tree or two:

```
example1, example2 :: Tree Int String
example1 = Node (Node Nil 4 "Hello" Nil) 7 "there" (Node Nil 21 "hi" Nil)
example2 = Node example1 34 "well" (Node Nil 55 "This" (Node (Node Nil 73 "one's" Nil) 102 "much" (Node Nil 132 "bigger" Nil)))
```

Your function

```
treeprint (Node l k d r) =  treeprint l  ++ show k ++ show d ++ treeprint r 
treeprint Nil = ""
```

compiles OK but because there are no spaces or brackets, the output is confusing:

```
*Main> putStrLn $ treeprint example1
4"Hello"7"there"21"hi"
*Main> putStrLn $ treeprint example2
4"Hello"7"there"21"hi"34"well"55"This"73"one's"102"much"132"bigger"
```

It's in order, but squashed together, and the tree structure is gone.

### More brackets, more spaces, more clarity

Let's rewrite it with brackets and spaces around each tree:

```
tree_print (Node l k d r) = " (" ++ treeprint l  ++ show k ++ ":" ++ show d ++ treeprint r ++ ") "
tree_print Nil = ""
```

so it's much clearer now:

```
*Main> putStrLn $ tree_print example1
 ( (4:"Hello") 7:"there" (21:"hi") ) 
*Main> putStrLn $ tree_print example2
 ( ( (4:"Hello") 7:"there" (21:"hi") ) 34:"well" (55:"This" ( (73:"one's") 102:"much" (132:"bigger") ) ) )
```

### Flatten the tree and get even more brackets!

Maybe you don't want the brackets because the in order print is meant to flatten the tree. You could just keep the spaces and the `:` and it would work. Alternatively, define

```
toList :: Tree k d -> [(k,d)]
toList Nil = []
toList (Node t1 k d t2) = toList t1 ++ (k,d):toList t2
```

Which means you'd be able to use the `Show` instance for lists:

```
*Main> toList example1
[(4,"Hello"),(7,"there"),(21,"hi")]
*Main> toList example2
[(4,"Hello"),(7,"there"),(21,"hi"),(34,"well"),(55,"This"),(73,"one's"),(102,"much"),(132,"bigger")]
```

### Prettier

Here's a way to print the tree using a `Data.Tree.Pretty` from the [pretty-tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-tree) library.

I'll have to do some importing:

```
import qualified Data.Tree as T
import Data.Tree.Pretty
```

I've imported `Data.Tree` qualified because it also defines a data constructor `Node`. This means I'll use `T.Node` when I mean the imported tree, but just `Node` when I mean yours.

It uses rose trees (that can have as many subtrees as they like at each node):

```
data Tree a = Node {
        rootLabel :: a,         -- ^ label value
        subForest :: Forest a   -- ^ zero or more child trees
    }
```

and defines `drawVerticalTree :: Tree String -> String` which is what I'll use.
All we need to do is convert your tree to this tree, and we'll be in business:

```
toTree :: (Show k,Show d) => Tree k d -> T.Tree String
toTree Nil = T.Node "-" []
toTree (Node t1 k d t2) = T.Node (show k ++ ":" ++ show d) [toTree t1,toTree t2]
```

Now let's show (make a String) and print (output in the IO monad):

```
showtree :: (Show k, Show d) => Tree k d -> String
showtree = drawVerticalTree.toTree

printtree :: (Show k, Show d) => Tree k d -> IO ()
printtree = putStrLn.('\n':).showtree
```

Which gives nice output:

```
*Main> printtree example1

    7:"there"     
        |         
     ---------    
    /         \   
4:"Hello"  21:"hi"
    |         |   
    --        --  
   /  \      /  \ 
   -  -      -  -
```

And copes fairly gracefully with slightly larger examples:

```
*Main> printtree example2

                   34:"well"                   
                       |                       
         ------------------------              
        /                        \             
    7:"there"                55:"This"         
        |                        |             
     ---------       -------------             
    /         \     /             \            
4:"Hello"  21:"hi"  -         102:"much"       
    |         |                   |            
    --        --            ------------       
   /  \      /  \          /            \      
   -  -      -  -      73:"one's"  132:"bigger"
                           |            |      
                           --           --     
                          /  \         /  \    
                          -  -         -  -
```