# Haskell Tree splitting: Can someone please explain this line?

Tags: haskell

```
split s (Root x lst rst)
 | s < x = let (nlt, nrt) = split s lst in
     (nlt, Root x nrt rst)
```

Can someone please explain this line? I don't really get the `let` part.

I tried thinking about it, I have no idea if I got it right:
we bind `(nlt, nrt)`, to the result of `split s lst`;  and `split s lst` itself will be `(nlt, Root x nrt rst)`

Is that it?

Here's the complete code:

```
split :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> (Tree a, Tree a)
split _ Empty = (Empty, Empty)
split s (Root x lst rst)
 | s < x = let (nlt, nrt) = split s lst in
     (nlt, Root x nrt rst)
 | s > x = let (nlt, nrt) = split s rst in
         (Root x lst nlt, nrt)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> we bind `(nlt, nrt)`, to the result of `split s lst`

Yup - `split s lst` is a pair, and we're giving the names `nlt` and `nrt` to the two elements of the pair.

> and `split s lst` itself will be `(nlt, Root x nrt rst)`

No, `split s (Root x lst rst)` (the result of the whole function) will be `(nlt, Root x nrt rst)`.

### But what does the whole function do?

```
split :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> (Tree a, Tree a)
split _ Empty = (Empty, Empty)
split s (Root x lst rst)
 | s < x = let (nlt, nrt) = split s lst in
     (nlt, Root x nrt rst)
 | s > x = let (nlt, nrt) = split s rst in
         (Root x lst nlt, nrt)
```

Let's try that on some sample data:

```
> split 300 (Root 512 (Root 256 (Root 128 Empty Empty) (Root 384 Empty Empty)) Empty)
(Root 256 (Root 128 Empty Empty) Empty,Root 512 (Root 384 Empty Empty) Empty)
```

So we took a tree that had 512 as its root, and all the items smaller than it in the left subtree, and split it so that the first tree is made up of entries below 300, with those over 300 in the second. That looks like this:

[image]

### How does the line in question work?

First let's rewrite the code with expanded names:

```
split :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> (Tree a, Tree a)
split _ Empty = (Empty, Empty)
split s (Root x left_subtree right_subtree)
 | s < x = let (new_left_tree, new_right_tree) = split s left_subtree in
     (new_left_tree, Root x new_right_tree right_subtree)
 | s > x = let (new_left_tree, new_right_tree) = split s right_subtree in
         (Root x left_subtree new_left_tree, new_right_tree)
```

The guard `|s < x` means we're in the case that this `x` should go on the right.

First we split the left subtree `split s left_subtree`, givning us a `new_left_tree` and `new_right_tree`. The `new_left_tree` is the stuff that should go left, but the `new_right_tree` is combined with `x` and the original `right_subtree` to make up the bits that go on the right of `s`.

### What can we learn about the function from that?

The `right_subtree` gets left alone, because `s` belongs on the left of `x`, so the function is assuming the tree is already sorted in the sense that in `Root x l r`, everything in `l` is below `x` and everything in `r` is above `x`.

The `left_subtree` gets split, because some of it may be less than `s` and other bits more than `s`.

The part of `split s left_subtree` that now belongs on the right (because it's more than `s`) is called `new_right_tree`, and because the whole `left_subtree` was less than `x` and the `right_subtree`, all of the `new_right_tree` should still be to the left of both `x` and `right_subtree`. That's why we make `Root x new_right_tree right_subtree` to be the right hand answer in the pair (and `new_left_tree` on the left of the pair).

Here's a before and after diagram:

[image]

### Why not have more descriptive names then?

Good question. Let's do it:

```
split :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> (Tree a, Tree a)
split _ Empty = (Empty, Empty)
split s (Root this below_this above_this)

 | s < this = let (below_this_below_s, below_this_above_s) = split s below_this in
     (below_this_below_s,  Root  this  below_this_above_s  above_this)

 | s > this = let (above_this_below_s, above_this_above_s) = split s above_this in
         (Root  this  below_this above_this_below_s,  above_this_above_s)
```

OK, I think that answers my question: sometimes descriptive names can be confusing too!

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, I can't upvote the answer, I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Also, I have another question as to what the function actually does:
If our "s" element is less than the root x,
we return a pair of trees: the first element being the new left tree, and the second one being the old tree (+ swapped left subtree with a new right subtree)?

I'm trying to make sense of this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: AndrewC, you're a life saver.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Just drew it on paper, to get a better idea. It is super clear: for the left subtree, we join the trees & subtrees < s.
for the right subtree, we join the trees & subtrees > s

Functional programming (or haskell syntax) is way tougher to digest than OOP

Comment: AndrewC, too bad, we can't draw graphs on here.

Comment: It's more dense, but once you get used to it, it's great. I remember starting a project in an OOP language and once I'd written a page or two of helper classes, I thought "hang on a minute - that would've taken me a few lines in Haskell - and indeed it did. :) I had a friend that swore by C, who explained a two program he'd written for a niggly bibliography maintenance task. I wrote a bit of Haskell on the back of an envelope and explained it. "Is that it?" "Yes. Why - is your code roughly 10 times as long?" "Yes.".

Comment: @macguy We can get closer using Data.Tree.Pretty. See the section __Prettier__ in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439902/function-which-takes-a-binary-tree-and-prints-out-its-values-in-order/13441601#13441601)

Comment: Sounds interesting, but Haskell is a bit too dense for just one semester, the learning curve is harder

Comment: @macguy I've added a diagram just for fun.

Comment: Wow! Lucky you! At least you've got some free time.

Comment: @AndrewC, what tool did you use for visualization ?

Comment: @smartcaveman I drew it using SMART Notebook, which is available with SMART Technologies interactive whiteboards. I don't imagine that you would run to the expense of getting an interactive whiteboard just to get the free vector drawing package, even if it is very nice! It's just a load of text of different sizes and colours with a line that I cloned and flipped horizontally to get the pleasing symmetrical look.